# Automatically loading uploaded files from production Django server

Tags: django, file

What I'm looking for is a piece of Django middleware that catches a FileNotFound exception and attempts to rsync the file from the production webserver. This way you can develop your site with a copy of production data without having to continually rsync down all the uploaded files.

I'm sure I've seen a solution to this problem on the internets, but hours of Googleing have so far produced nothing. Anyone know of where to find this?

Comment: How come in your development environment some objects refer media from production? Do you sync database between environments? Then why don't you sync media files as well?

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility, but sometimes the data is a couple of gig. An automatic sync *on-demand* only gets the files required to stop the local dev server falling over.

Comment: The problem as I see it: let's say you are able to create a function that does the rsync correctly. What then? Whatever action you were trying to do on the file already failed. I think you should probably create a wrapper object instead and instead of using the standard `open('/path/to/file')` you use something like `open(SafeFile('/path/to/file'))`. If the file doesn't exist, the class first rsycns the file, then makes it available.

Comment: Yeah, that would work, and if I implement this myself I'll probably do just that. However I was sure someone else had already written this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I'd seen before is this:

http://menendez.com/blog/using-django-as-pass-through-image-proxy/

which doesn't catch the FileNotFound error, but the Http404 error, and then loads images from the live server. Unfortunately this doesn't fix the issue of FileNotFound when trying to read images off disk (for sizes etc).